# Building Apple Swift on ppc64le for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu, powerpc

We are trying to build Apple Swift on ppc64le Ubuntu16.04. We built it on ppc64le using a build script at the following link:- https://github.com/ppc64le/build-scripts/blob/60b7885f4f0915a8671b3cfb86ddbb65f9b988a8/swift/swift41_ubuntu_16.04.sh

With this we were able to run the 'swiftc' and REPL environment for some basic "Hello World" type of code. However for complex codes, like import Foundation, it fails(probably due to Package manager issues). When we use "import Foundation" with swift, compile error occurs as below is seen:

```
(swift) import Foundation
<REPL Input>:1:8: error: no such module 'Foundation'
import Foundation
       ^
```

We are trying to build Swift 4.2(since Swift v4.1 has been released now and no further development is happening on this branch.) on Power8/LE (ppc64le) using the build-toolchain, in order to build the Swift package manager and other tools.

We are seeing a crash which is traceable till following function in HeapObject.cpp file:

```
static HeapObject *_swift_retain_(HeapObject *object) {
  SWIFT_RT_TRACK_INVOCATION(object, swift_retain);
  if (isValidPointerForNativeRetain(object))
    object->refCounts.increment(1);
  return object;
}
```

Beyond this debugging using simple print statements is tricky and the code flow is unclear. Breakpoints cannot be set since building code in debug mode is not possible as it runs out of resources and hangs. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Any more outputs, errors can be shared.

Looking forward to port Apple Swift on Ubuntu16.04.

Regards,
Sarvesh Tamba

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tried to build Swift 4.2 in debug mode. Applied patch at "https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/16425" for "stdlib/public/SwiftShims/System.h". Facing similar issues as reported above in "https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7441" :-

Fatal error: file /root/swift-source/swift/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift, line 466
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00003fffaaf67150 <unavailable> + 6517072
--- bootstrap: error: build failed with exit status -5
utils/build-script: fatal error: command terminated with a non-zero exit status 1, aborting

Comment: Any insights on the above errors anyone?

Comment: On closer investigation, realised that the string implemetation has changed in Swift 4.2 from that in Swift 4.1 to a large extent. 
The crash involves changes in String.swift besides the newly introduced StringGuts.swift and StringObject.swift files.

In the StringGuts.swift file there are comments such as "// FIXME: what about ppc64 and s390x?" indicating that the support for PowerPC(ppc64) might still be incomplete.

Can we confirm that the new string implementation in Swift 4.2 has complete support for PowerPC(ppc64)?

Comment: Built and verified Swift 5.0 master on PowerPC(powerpc64le). I was able to run all the samples given in https://swift.org/getting-started/ which confirms that 'swiftc'(Swift compiler), REPL environment and LLDB debugger are working correctly. Also package manager seems to work fine. Built a sample package using the ported Swift 5.0 binaries.

More details in this https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7441